# placing components using GridBagLayout() is not giving desired result

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, gridbaglayout

I want to create a data entry tab as follows along with few buttons:

[image]

where width of all textfields is 3, heights of 'Name' and 'Amount paid' are 1 whereas height of address is 3. There is a vertical gap of 1 line between them.

For this purpose I wrote the code as follows: (data_panel is seperated out from button_panel so as to get better component placements)

```
private JLabel label_name;
private JTextField text_name;

private JLabel label_address;
private JTextField text_address;

private JLabel label_amount_paid;
private JTextField text_amount_paid;

private JButton button_add_member;
private JButton button_remove_member;
private JButton button_remove_all;

public TabPanesAddRemove() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    JPanel data_panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); // data entry panel
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    label_name = new JLabel("Name: ");
    data_panel.add(label_name, gbc);

    text_name = new JTextField(20);
    text_name.setName("name");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    data_panel.add(text_name, gbc);

    label_address = new JLabel("Address: ");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    data_panel.add(label_address, gbc);

    text_address = new JTextField(20);
    text_address.setName("address");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.gridheight = 3;
    data_panel.add(text_address, gbc);

    label_amount_paid = new JLabel("Amount Paid: ");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 7;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    // gbc.gridheight = 1;
    data_panel.add(label_amount_paid);

    text_amount_paid = new JTextField(20);
    text_amount_paid.setName("amount");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 7;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    data_panel.add(text_amount_paid);

    add(data_panel);

    JPanel buttons_panel = new JPanel(); // button panel
    button_add_member = new JButton(BUTTON_ADD);
    button_remove_member = new JButton(BUTTON_REMOVE);
    button_remove_all = new JButton(BUTTON_REMOVE_ALL);
    buttons_panel.add(button_add_member);
    buttons_panel.add(button_remove_member);
    buttons_panel.add(button_remove_all);
    add(buttons_panel);

    Event ev = new Event();
    button_add_member.addActionListener(ev);
    button_remove_member.addActionListener(ev);
    button_remove_all.addActionListener(ev);
}
```

This code gave me the output as below:

[image]

looking closely:

[image]

I tried various changes including those of using `gbc.fill` and different dimensions in `JTextField()`, `gbc.gridx` and `gbc.gridy`, etc. But I'm unable to get desired result.

Can anybody please help me to sort out the problem?

Comment: may I suggest you use the WindowBuilder plugin? Not only does it save you alot of work, you can also learn from looking at the generated code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you out. I know its not exactly what your looking for, but it demonstrates how to use the GB layout fairly well I guess:

```
public class MainF extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainF f = new MainF();
    f.setVisible(true);

}


public MainF() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 300);

    Dimension tfSize = new Dimension(200, 25);
    JPanel dataP = new JPanel();
    dataP.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Name:");

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;

    dataP.add(label, c);

    JTextField tf = new JTextField(30);
    tf.setMinimumSize(tfSize);
    tf.setMaximumSize(tfSize);
    tf.setPreferredSize(tfSize);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    dataP.add(tf, c);

    label = new JLabel("Address:");
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    dataP.add(label, c);

    tf = new JTextField(30);
    tf.setMinimumSize(tfSize);
    tf.setMaximumSize(tfSize);
    tf.setPreferredSize(tfSize);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    dataP.add(tf, c);

    label = new JLabel("Amount Paid:");
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    dataP.add(label, c);

    tf = new JTextField(30);
    tf.setMinimumSize(tfSize);
    tf.setMaximumSize(tfSize);
    tf.setPreferredSize(tfSize);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    dataP.add(tf, c);

    JButton button = new JButton("Add Member");
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 5;
    dataP.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("Remove Member");
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 5;
    dataP.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("Remove All Members");
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 4;
    c.gridy = 5;
    dataP.add(button, c);
    this.add(dataP);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you forgot to pass the `GridBagConstraints` when you added `label_amount_paid` and `text_amount_paid`

```
label_amount_paid = new JLabel("Amount Paid: ");
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//...
data_panel.add(label_amount_paid); // Missing constraints

text_amount_paid = new JTextField(20);
text_amount_paid.setName("amount");
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//...
data_panel.add(text_amount_paid); // Missing constraints
```

Remember, by default, the x/y positions are 0 based.

```
label_amount_paid = new JLabel("Amount Paid: ");
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//...
data_panel.add(label_amount_paid, gbc);

text_amount_paid = new JTextField(20);
text_amount_paid.setName("amount");
//...
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
data_panel.add(text_amount_paid, gbc);
```

[image: Payout]

I'd also be very careful with `gridWidth` and `gridHeight`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out missing constraints... But still output is not as desired.. what could be the problem? If height and widths are not visible as per given constraints, what is use of provision of such constraints as `gridx`, `gridy`, `gridwidth` and `gridheight` ?

Comment: Use a JTextArea instead of a JTextField, set its columns and rows according to your requirements. gridx/gridy refer to the cell position a component should occupy, the gridwidth/height determines how how many columns/rows the component should expand over. Remember though, unlike GridLayout, the column/row sizes are determine by the components that occupy it, meaning even if a component expands n number of rows, of nothing else exists in those rows, then it will have no effect on the component...

Comment: What is you current output and what remains to be wrong with?